# how hide p:commandbutton with jquery use primefaces 3.4

Tags: primefaces

I intend to hide a `<p:commandbutton>` through a jquery form, and I can not access the object primefaces button, the form itself. I'm using primefaces 3.4.

I hide a button: save, in one form, where the button is: edit:

Answer (score 1):

you can use the rendered attribute and set it to false.

```
<p:commandButton rendered="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the button through its ID, just add the `display:none` css property:

```
$("#yourButtonsId").css("display", "none);
```

When the button is inside a form without `prependId=false`, the button ID is something similar to `:testForm1:testButton` your jQuery selector will look like this:

```
$("#testForm1\\:testButton").css("display", "none");
```